Debian12 with KDE5: How to make Wayland the default?
I thought it was enough to Log Out then in the upper left of the lockscreen clicking the dropdown to change it from "Plasma (X11)" to "Plasma (Wayland)" would be enough but apparently it isn't.
I checked if I was using Wayland with loginctl show-session 1 -p Type (replace "1" with your session number shown by running loginctl) after a reboot and it showed X11.

After changing to "Plasma (Wayland)" and logging back in, open "Login Screen (SDDM)" in KDE from the search or by going to System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Login Screen (SDDM) -> then click on the two login screens there and for each click on "Behavior...".
If "Automatically log in:" is enabled there, change the dropdown next to "with session" to "Plasma (Wayland)".
If no automatic log in is configured changing the dropdown in the login screen and logging in once could theoretically be enough.
